# JSON is returning an array of numbers instead of the value in an object within the JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to go through this JSON object and grab some values out of it.

```
let currentPage = "
{
    "sys": {
        "space": {
            "sys": {
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Space",
                "id": "xaswoie0ncrg"
            }
        },
        "id": "7lqAYzwP92G9TMDBUVnadp",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2020-07-30T18:08:33.159Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-07-30T18:22:50.276Z",
        "environment": {
            "sys": {
                "id": "master",
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Environment"
            }
        },
        "revision": 2,
        "contentType": {
            "sys": {
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "ContentType",
                "id": "landingPage"
            }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
    },
    "fields": {
        "pageTitle": "Leading the next generation of renewable fuels",
        "heroImage": {
            "sys": {
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Asset",
                "id": "vnjfnYzSyhqOjKlmNmBGb"
            }
        },
        "pageZone": [
            {
                "sys": {
                    "type": "Link",
                    "linkType": "Entry",
                    "id": "3aQvORUYowW0SoofuvHUov"
                }
            },
            {
                "sys": {
                    "type": "Link",
                    "linkType": "Entry",
                    "id": "Qfj1hNJ9euSkBcAQEDaN5"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}"
```

I then parse the JSON:

`let currentPage2 = JSON.parse(currentPage);`

Now here's the issue.
If log this in the console:

`console.log(Object.keys(currentPage2.fields.pageZone[0].sys.id));`

Node returns this in the terminal:

```
[
  '0',  '1',  '2',  '3',  '4',
  '5',  '6',  '7',  '8',  '9',
  '10', '11', '12', '13', '14',
  '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
  '20', '21'
]
```

I want to use this:

```
console.log(Object.keys(currentPage2.fields.pageZone[0].sys.id).value);
//with expected value of "3aQvORUYowW0SoofuvHUov"
```

Instead, it returns `undefined`. I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried using `JSON.stringify` etc and parsing it again, but it still behaves this way.

Comment: just use `console.log(currentPage2.fields.pageZone[0].sys.id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `currentPage2.fields.pageZone[0].sys.id`. There is no need for `Object.keys` at all, unless you want each index of the string.

Comment: God, simple error. I was using this for another purpose and ended up copying it. Thanks for that.

Comment: @AnthonySchanen No problem.

Answer (score 1):

`currentPage2.fields.pageZone[0].sys.id` is a string, and since `Object.keys` will interpret the string as an iterable, the keys will be the indexes of each characters.